# Is there a more efficient way of fuzzy string searching than BK Trees?

Tags: string, algorithm, fuzzy-search

For an algorithms class, I am doing a project which investigates any particular algorithm.  I chose to investigate [BK Trees (Burkhard-Keller Trees)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree&ei=kCKbT4W1K8SG6QGYmsWUDw&usg=AFQjCNHOfhLHevquCoOKgctddM2Y2NZ9gQ&sig2=TuVA1qzqd0u8CI8PmNoACg).  A BK Tree is associated with fuzzy string searches (e.g. spell check, word recommendations).  However, it seems that BK Trees don't perform that quickly, and could even be outdated.  There aren't a lot of good, academic sources out there.  Are there any faster, more efficient algorithms out there for fuzzy string matching?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few common approaches

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgtrgm.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance